# how to grep ASCII control character

Tags: grep, ascii

If I have a file containing [ASCII control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart), for example, `^A` (Start of Header).

How can I find it using grep in Linux?

Comment: With bash: `grep $'\01' file`

Comment: `grep '[[:cntrl:]]'`? It's really not clear if you want to find one specific control char or all control chars and if you find them what it is you want output.

Comment: @Cyrus I see OP mentioned your comment solved his issue. You may want to post an answer so that it is clear

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [seen in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092885/how-to-grep-ascii-control-character#comment48298380_30092885), this solved the issue:

```
grep $'\01' file
```

Comment: ah, should look in bash docs, not grep :) https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Comment: @Eric exactly : )

Comment: Note that the above is in **octal** format, if I am not mistaken. You can also search for the usual escapes and hexadecimal ones (see @Eric 's comment above for escape sequences). To search for the FORM FEED char you can e.g. use either `$'\xC'` or `$'\f`', see [any ascii table like this one](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) for hex-positions.

Comment: this does not seem to work with linefeed :(

Comment: This does not work for me (GNU grep 3.4): `grep -a '[:cntrl:]` does not match the same as `grep -a $'\00'`. For example piping in `printf "hell0\x0\nworld\n:-)\x0:-(\n"`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Perl regular expressions which can be enabled in `grep` with `-P` option:

```
grep -P "\x01" file
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519026/89254), awk portably finds control characters

```bash
awk '/\01/'
```